# How to install OBS on Google Cloud / AWS VM properly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have started experimenting with 24/7 live streams, and I have a Linux Ubuntu VM on the google cloud platform that I want to start streaming from.

The problem is that when I try to launch OBS on the VM, the next error pops up: "Failed to initialize video. Your GPU may not be supported, or your graphics drivers may need to be updated." [(Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4EKF.jpg)

From what I understand, this problem appears because my VM doesn't have a GPU at all - only CPU. I tried installing OpenGL for the hope that it will solve the problem, but it didn't help.

**Is there any way that I can run OBS on an Ubuntu VM?**
**And if there is, what is it, and do I have to use a VM with a GPU? if not, what services do you suggest to stream 24/7?**

Thanks in advance! (:

Comment: Could you please let us know if you are using a guide for your installation? if so, could you share it? if not, could you please share the steps you are following? that information could be helpful if some one wants to reproduce your issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an instance with GPU, check out the NVIDIA Click to Deploy images in the GCP Marketplace. They allow you to attach NVIDIA Tesla GPU's. I've demoed this for media encoding and it's been handy on occasion when my local machine can't handle this easily. If you find a solution, please update us here. I'd like to run OBS in the cloud as well. Going to recommend GCP over AWS for this.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to the error message supported GPU is required for your use case. Yes, by default Google Cloud VM instances doesn't have GPU at all.

**To solve this issue** you can find an image at the Marketplace as it was suggested by *@user13730079* or you can create a new VM instance (or you can try to change machine type of existing VM instance) by following the documentation [Creating VMs with attached GPUs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/create-vm-with-gpus) section [Creating VMs with attached GPUs (other GPU types)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/create-vm-with-gpus#create-new-gpu-vm):

> You can create a VM with one or more GPUs using the Google Cloud
> Console, the gcloud command-line tool, or the Compute Engine API.

Step by step instructions you can find at the documentation.

Keep in mind that there are some [restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus#restrictions) while using GPU like:

> - If you want to use Tesla K80 GPUs with your instances, the instances cannot use the Intel Skylake or later CPU platforms.
> - GPUs are currently only supported with general-purpose N1 machine types.
> - GPU instances must stop for host maintenance events, but can automatically restart.

and so on.

In addition, please have a look at the [OBS System Requirements](https://obsproject.com/wiki/System-Requirements) and [GCE VM usage example](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/running-obs-on-google-gcp-cloud-vm-with-tesla-t4-gpu-it-works.135072/#post-496371).